# Rank of a matrix using colunm space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank, gaussian-elimination

I'd like some verification of my solution method since I don't have any solution at hand. I'm given the following matrix and asked to determine the rank of it in function of  $x$:

$\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 2 & -6 & 8 \\
3 & 3 & -9 & 8 \\
1 & 1 & x & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

I started with the fact that for any given matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ the column space $C(A) = \mathbb{R}^m$. In this case, the column space is given by:

$$C(A) = vct \{\begin{pmatrix} 
2 \\
3 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 
2 \\
3 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 
-6 \\
-9 \\
x \\
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 
8 \\
8 \\
4 \\
\end{pmatrix}\}$$ Since the column space $C(A)$ is $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{R}^4$ depending on $x$, I set out to find for which value of $x$ the vector $(-6, -9, x)^T$ would be a linear combination of the other vectors indicating that the column space would be equal to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Solving the following system of linear equations:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 2 & 8 & | & -6 \\
3 & 3 & 8 & | & -9 \\
1 & 1 & 4 & | & x \\
\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 4 & | & x \\
0 & 0 & -4 & | & -9 - 3x \\
0 & 0 & 0 & | & -6-2x \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

That the matrix is unsolvable when $-6-2x \neq 0$ or when $x \neq -3$. Thus I came to the conclusion that

$$ rank(A) = 3 \iff x = -3$$
$$ rank(A) = 4 \iff x \neq -3$$

I have thus no idea if this solution is correct. If not, could someone tell me how I should solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be correct: the rank of $A$ can never be $4$ since the column space is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. The first and last column are linearly independent, so the rank is at least $2$.

Depending on $x$ it might be equal to $2$ or $3$ and your calculation shows that the rank is $3$ as long as $x\neq -3$ and $2$ when $x=-3$.

Comment: so the max rank a matrix has is the amount of rows in the matrix? And then depending on how many columns are linearly independent you see that it is less than this? How would you calculate this effectively since I presume calculating every single L.C. isn't the way to do it?

Comment: @MatthiasK. Row reduction until you reach row echelon form. The number of pivots is the rank of the matrix.